# Remove "do you want to close this window" message from terminal (osx)

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I have an osx (10.11) computer set on a timer to restart at a certain time each day. There is a terminal shell that is running a script and this blocks the restart by prompting a "Do you want to close this window" message when it tries to close terminal?

Is there a way to remove this prompt, or have osx force quit all apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a *preference* which you can alter for `Terminal`, e.g., to simply close the window.  See screenshot:

[image: preferences showing window-close]

Comment: perfect, that's is exactly what I needed. Thank you